# Romanian language in latex

Tags: bibtex

I've tried to write in LaTeX (in TeXShop on mac) but I didn't succeed having also a romanian alphabet into my pdf word.

I have tried to write like this, but it's still not working. any hint will be very well received.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{combelow}% provides \cb to place comma below character

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ș}{\cb{s}}
\newunicodechar{ț}{\cb{t}}

\begin{document}
\cb{s} and \cb{t}

ș and ț
\end{document}
```

I solved this problem and **this** works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\usepackage{combelow}

\useshorthands{'}
\defineshorthand{'s}{\cb{s}}
\defineshorthand{'t}{\cb{t}}
\defineshorthand{'S}{\cb{S}}
\defineshorthand{'T}{\cb{T}}

\begin{document}

Bucure'sti 't 'T 'S

\end{document}
```

enjoy.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What's the question? Because in my test, this produces the expected output.

Comment: I want to write a text using also 'ș' and 'ț'.

Comment: And where's the problem? If I type `porțile` (one of the few Romanian words I know), I get the expected result. There are problems, of course, because such composite characters will not participate in hyphenation, so you may be willing to switch to XeLaTeX and `fontspec`.

Comment: Do you get errors when you compile your example? Can you show the log-file?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer i posted in a new answer for my question.

Comment: Don't use answers to expand your question. Edit the question instead. And the error says that the sty is not installed, so use the texlive manager  tlmgr to install it.

Comment: I'll add here my configuration also:
\useshorthands{'}
\defineshorthand{'s}{\cb{s}}
\defineshorthand{'t}{\cb{t}}
\defineshorthand{'S}{\cb{S}}
\defineshorthand{'T}{\cb{T}}
\defineshorthand{'I}{\^{I}}   & Î
\defineshorthand{'i}{\^{i}}   % î
\defineshorthand{'a}{\u{a}} % ă

\useshorthands{`}
\defineshorthand{`a}{\^{a}}  % â

Answer (score 12):

With the current release of LaTeX (2016/03/31), `newunicodechar` is not necessary, as the codes for `ș` and `ț` have been included in the UTF-8 support. You don't even need `combelow`, the command to use for the default installation is `\textcommabelow`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}

\begin{document}
\textcommabelow{s} and \textcommabelow{t}

ș and ț
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[romanian]{babel}
    \usepackage{combelow}

\begin{document}

    \^{I}mi pare bine de cuno\cb{s}tin\cb{t}\u{a}.

    Nu vorbesc rom\^{a}ne\cb{s}te.

    Aeroglisor meu este plin de \cb{t}ipari!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you will need to install (from MiKTeX Console as Admin -> Packages) the "babel-romanian" package:[image]
Then in TeXstudio, just add these two lines:

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Btw, dacă este cineva interesat și de Speck Checking, în Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Language Checking se poate da Import Dictionary și apoi se alege acel fișier .otx pentru limba română (descărcat de pe OpenOffice)... Si voila, spell check ca în Word!

Comment: From OP question its follows, that (s)he have installed Romanian babel, recent in the recent  LaTeX installation `utf8` support Romanian specific characters (see @egreg answer).